# An application of population Spearman rank correlation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, spearman-rho

Let $W$ and $S$ are two positive valued continuous random variable. Suppose the Spearman rank correlation between $W$ and $SW+g(S)$ is zero, where
$g: [0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is a convex function with a constraint that $g$ can't be of the form $g(x)=cx$, $c$ is a constant.

So we have (from the definition of population Spearman rank correlation),
$$P\left(S_1W_1+g(S_1)<S_3W_3+g(S_3),W_1<W_2<W_3\right)=\frac{1}{12},$$
 where $(S_1,W_1),(S_2,W_2)$ and $(S_3,W_3)$  are three i.i.d pairs of $(S,W)$.

Is it possible, there exist some $\theta$ such that the following equations holds simultaneously,

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
 &&P\left(S_1W_1+g(S_1)<S_3W_3+g(S_3),W_1<W_2<W_3\right)=\frac{1}{12},\; \mbox{and},\;\\[2ex]
 &&P\left(S_1W_1+\theta S_1<S_3W_3+\theta S_3),W_1<W_2<W_3\right)=\frac{1}{12}??.
\end{array}
\end{equation}

**Tried:** Suppose there exist some $\theta$ for which the above holds. So
 \begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
 &&P\left(S_1W_1-S_3W_3<g(S_3)-g(S_1),W_1<W_2<W_3\right)=
 P\left(S_1W_1-S_3W_3<\theta( S_3-S_1)),W_1<W_2<W_3\right).
\end{array}
\end{equation}
From here can I say anything about the form of $g$?